# Hangman game effect of setSolved() is delayed

Tags: reactjs

I have a hangman game that almost works. The issue is that when I got all letters correct, YOU WIN message is not displayed until I click on a letter once more.

I'll list only parts that I feel relevant.

Game.js is a container.

Game contains state:

```
state = {
        lives: 12,
        solution: 'my name is logan',
        correctUsedLetters: [],
        availableLetters: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'],
        usedLetters: [],
        solved: false
};
```

And many handlers including setSolvedHandler:

```
setSolvedHandler = () => {
        const solution = this.state.solution.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/-/g, '').split('');
        const compare = [ ...this.state.correctUsedLetters].sort();
        const unique = solution.filter(
            (elem,index,self) => (index===self.indexOf(elem))
        ).sort();

        const solved = JSON.stringify(unique) === JSON.stringify(compare);

        this.setState({
            solved: solved
        });
};
```

This handler sets solved to true if correctUsedLetters match solution, in effect if the player has solved the puzzle.

Also inside Game.js Letters is rendered:

```
<div className={classes.LettersAndHangman}>
                    <Hangman lives={this.state.lives} />
                    <Letters setSolved={this.setSolvedHandler} solution={this.state.solution} correct={this.guessedCorrectHandler} incorrect={this.guessedIncorrectHandler} 
                    feed={this.state.availableLetters}
                    />
</div>
```

Game.js calls on Letters so let's have a look at that.

Letters.js has state called lettersMap that contains each letter of the alphabet with a boolean value indicating whether the letter has been clicked or not.

```
const [lettersMap, setLettersMap]=useState(
        {
            "a":false,"b":false,"c":false,"d":false,"e":false,"f":false,"g":false,"h":false,"i":false,"j":false,"k":false,"l":false,"m":false,"n":false,"o":false,"p":false,"q":false,"r":false,"s":false,"t":false,"u":false,"v":false,"w":false,"x":false,"y":false,"z":false
        }
);
```

It contains playHandler which tests whether the clicked letter is a correct one or not. But we'll skip this for now.

More importantly, it contains updateClickedHandler which sets the boolean to true for the letter clicked. This updates the lettersMap.

```
const updateClickedHandler = (letter) => {
        setLettersMap(
            {
                ...lettersMap,[letter]:true
            }
        );
};
```

Then two things are rendered from Letters.js. AvailableLetter and DisabledLetter. AvailableLetter represents a letter that has not been clicked. DisabledLetter represents a letter that has been clicked and now disabled from clicking again.

```
 const renderedLetters = Object.keys(lettersMap).map(
        (letter,i)=>{
          if (!lettersMap[letter])     //letter is not yet clicked
          {
            return (
                <AvailableLetter updateClicked={updateClickedHandler} setSolved={props.setSolved} play={()=>playHandler(letter)} correct={()=>props.correct(letter)} incorrect={()=>props.incorrect(letter)} solution={props.solution} key={i} alphabet={letter} />
            )
          }
          else                         //letter is clicked
          { 
            return (
                <DisabledLetter alphabet={letter} key={i} />
            )
          }
        }
);
```

Here are codes for AvailableLetter and DisabledLetter:

```
const AvailableLetter = (props) => {

    const setStuff = () => {
      if (props.play()) {
        props.correct();
      }
      else {
        props.incorrect();
      }

      props.setSolved();
      props.updateClicked(props.alphabet);
    };

    return (
        <Ax>
          <span className={classes.AvailableLetter} onClick={setStuff}>{props.alphabet}</span>
        </Ax>
    );
}
```

```
const DisabledLetter = (props) => {
    return (
    <span className={classes.DisabledLetter} >{props.alphabet}</span>
    );
};
```

Now I'll introduce Model.js which displays messages YOU WIN or GAME OVER.

```
const modal = (props) => {
    let show = props.gameOver() || props.solved ? true : false;

    const attachedClasses = [ classes.Message ];
    if (!show) {
        attachedClasses.push(classes.Hide);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Backdrop show={show} />
            <div className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >
                {props.gameOver()?<p>GAME OVER</p>:null}
                {props.solved?<p>YOU WIN!</p>:null}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Investigating the code, the show becomes true if either game over or solved. This value is used to show/hide backdrop. It is also used to show/hide messages.

Then depending on game over or solved you get appropriate message: GAME OVER or YOU WIN.

I'm not sure yet what the root of the problem is, but the issue is that YOU WIN does not display even when the puzzle is solved until you click on one more letter(that doesn't do anything other than trigger the message).

Currently, setSolved() is called inside AvailableLetter.js when span is clicked. It seems like effect of calling setSolved when a letter is clicked is somehow delayed.

I'll try to construct the question succinctly as I can. Thank you for your patience.

You can get complete source here:
https://github.com/gunitinug/hangmanclicked/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a hack:

Inside Game.js I wrote function checkSolvedWithoutStateChange:

```
// A hack for Modal.js
    checkSolvedWithoutStateChange = () => {
        const solution = this.state.solution.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/-/g, '').split('');
        const compare = [ ...this.state.correctUsedLetters].sort();
        const unique = solution.filter(
            (elem,index,self) => (index===self.indexOf(elem))
        ).sort();

        const solved = JSON.stringify(unique) === JSON.stringify(compare);
        return solved;
    };
```

Then, I passed it to render inside Game.js:

```
<Modal checkSolved={this.checkSolvedWithoutStateChange} gameOver={this.gameOverHandler} />
```

Here's Modal.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Backdrop from './Backdrop/Backdrop';
import classes from './Modal.module.css';

const modal = (props) => {
    let show = props.gameOver() || props.checkSolved() ? true : false;

    const attachedClasses = [ classes.Message ];
    if (!show) {
        attachedClasses.push(classes.Hide);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Backdrop show={show} />
            <div className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >
                {props.gameOver()?<p>GAME OVER</p>:null}
                {props.checkSolved()?<p>YOU WIN!</p>:null}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default modal;
```

Now it is fixed, but I would like to know a better way to do this avoiding this 'hack'. :D

Answer (score 0):

After learning about redux I'm guessing the functionality in concern here is an asynchronous call. So I need to use redux-thunk, for example, and handle it asynchronously.

I'll follow up on this later and fix the project properly. :)

UPDATE:
I've now learned that React Hooks can only be used inside a functional component OR inside a custom hook. I can't use them, for example, inside a function or inside an if statement. I believe I made these mistake in my code right now. I need to fix them.

UPDATE:
I just learned that using useEffect in the following way in functional component is the same as calling componentDidMount in class component.

```
useEffect(()=>{},[]);
```

In this configuration with the dependency [], it gets called just once when the component is first rendered, and just this once. In comparison, the following useEffect causes an infinite loop:

```
useEffect(()=> {
   setCustomState({});   // this is a custom set method in useState.
});
```

This is because, in this configuration useEffect is called after every render, and inside of it, setCustomState triggers re-render and useEffect is called again, and so on.

UPDATE:
The useCallback() might be useful also. It caches a function so that when the class is rerendered(and therefore function is recreated) so it avoids creating an infinite loop.

Basically, a function wrapped inside useCallback is cached and not recreated when the component is re-rendered.

Upon creating the function, this is the same as that function being 'changed'. So the following is executed:

```
useEffect(()=>{},[f]);    // this gets executed everytime f is 'changed'
```

If

```
const cachedF = useCallback(f);
```

Then, useEffect is only executed once because f is cached.